# Github Commit Push raises 403 Error due to nonlocality

Tags: git, github

I am trying to push a commit to my repository. But I am getting a curious 403 error message from github that I can't find any documentation for on the internet.

Specifically, when I try to push my commit with "git push", I get this error:

remote: Permission to praveenkulkarni1996/awesome-program-synthesis.git denied to nonlocality.
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/praveenkulkarni1996/awesome-program-synthesis/': The requested URL returned error: 403

One possible explanation for non-locality is that I have changed countries, but I don't know why that should be a bother. Please let me know if you need me to share any further information.

[image: Error Message]

Comment: Please see the error message link at the very top for a screenshot of this error.

Comment: I don't think "nonlocality" means anything about your location. There is a [GitHub account with that name](https://github.com/nonlocality). GitHub thinks that's you. Is there any chance that you're using somebody else's credentials? Is your `user.email` configured properly, and do you have that email address registered with GitHub?

Comment: @Chris you were absolutely correct. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

403 means forbidden and is a standard http response code.

For me it looks like you are trying to push to a repository without permission.

Could you check the output of `git config user.name` and `git config user.email` and if they fit to yours